# What's the best practice way to convert enum to string?

Tags: c#, string, enums

I have enum like this:

```
public enum ObectTypes
{
    TypeOne,
    TypeTwo,
    TypeThree,
    ...
    TypeTwenty
 }
```

then I need to convert this enum to string. Now Im doing this that way:

```
public string ConvertToCustomTypeName(ObjectTypes typeObj)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    switch (typeObj)
    {
        case ObjectTypes.TypeOne: result = "This is type T123"; break;
        case ObjectTypes.TypeTwo: result = "Oh man! This is type T234"; break;
        ...
        case ObjectTypes.TypeTwenty: result = "This is type last"; break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Im quite sure that there is better way do do this, Im looking for some good practice solution.

**EDIT**: There is no one pattern in result string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also FWIW you don't need the result object at all you just return those strings and be able to get rid of the break statements too.

Comment: @Chris Marisic.
Yes, you have right, but that variable is only for better reading :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use the `[Description]` attribute from `System.ComponentModel`

Example:

```
public enum RoleType
{
    [Description("Allows access to public information")] Guest = 0,
    [Description("Allows access to the blog")] BlogReader = 4,
}
```

Then to read from it I do

```
public static string ReadDescription<T>(T enumMember)
{
    var type = typeof (T);

    var fi = type.GetField(enumMember.ToString());
    var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[]) 
            fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DescriptionAttribute), false);
    return attributes.Length > 0 ? 
        attributes[0].Description : 
        enumMember.ToString();
}
```

Then usage

`ReadDescription(RoleType.Guest);`

**Note:** this solution assumes a single culture application as nothing was specifically asked about multiple cultures. If you are in a situation that you need to handle multiple cultures I would use the `DescriptionAttribute` or similar to store a key to a culture aware resource file. While you could store the enum member directly in the .resx file that would create the tightest coupling possible. I see no reason why you would want to couple the internal workings of your application (the enum member names) to key values that exist for internationalization purposes.

Comment: This is awfully slow - may or may not matter, depending on the usage.

Comment: Premature optimization is the devil. If performance is a serious consideration you can implement caching and only ever need to read each enum member once. I use this to populate drop down lists so I cache singleton copies of my Code/Value pair enums in my model after I iterate over the enum once. If I was concerned about the reflection cost I would actually cache it inside the ReadDescription method in somekind of dictionary or hashtable etc.

Comment: This is a great technique for dealing with enums, although it would be a lot cleaner if the enum itself had a `GetDescription` method or some such (and if you could put the description *after* the enumeration).

Comment: I have all of these methods in a static class for working with Enums however I might try making them extension methods instead. So I can directly do `RoleType.Guest.ReadDescription()` instead of `EnumParser.ReadDescription(RoleType.Guest)`

Comment: Too bad you can't inherit from `enum`. I'd love to see the extension method version, if you've got the motivation. I'll pay you back with a drive-by.

Comment: @MusiGenisis: `enum` types inherit from `System.Enum`.

Comment: This method is also not culture aware. This is okay if you will ever only ship in one language, but as soon as you either require a different language or one customer requests a customisation, you end up having to keep another copy of the compiled dll.

Comment: @slugster if I needed to ship culture aware I would use either the enum name or the enum description to lookup into a culture matching resx file or similar. I would still likely use the description attribute or similar, I see no reason why my enum values should be 100% fully coupled to resx keys.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic I'm not sure why you added this (very) late comment, but you should consider adding to your answer (rather than leaving info or commentary as a comment, which can get lost in the noise).

Comment: @slugster it was just upvoted which brought my attention back to it

Answer (score 9):

If you need a custom string, the best option would be to make a `Dictionary< ObjectTypes, string>`, and just do a dictionary lookup.

If you're fine with the default ToString() functionality, just use `typeObj.ToString();`

For the dictionary approach, you could do:

```
private static Dictionary<ObjectTypes, string> enumLookup;

static MyClass()
{
    enumLookup = new Dictionary<ObjectTypes, string>();
    enumLookup.Add(ObjectTypes.TypeOne, "This is type T123");
    enumLookup.Add(ObjectTypes.TypeTwo, "This is type T234");
    // enumLookup.Add...

}
```

Your method becomes:

```
public string ConvertToCustomTypeName(ObjectTypes typeObj)
{
     // Shouldn't need TryGetValue, unless you're expecting people to mess  with your enum values...
     return enumLookup[typeObj];
}
```

Comment: I feel the need to point out that for compact enums (no large value gaps), a List<string> would be much more efficient.

Comment: @Simon: Yes, potentially - although this is more flexible, for any value type in the enum, with any arbitrary enum value...

Comment: @Simon: Although, that's only true, too, if the enum values start at or near 0... You start getting "values" that can't easily be converted into list indices, and the hashing will be faster.

Answer (score 4):

Use the suggested Resources way:

```
string GetName(Enum e) {
     return Properties.Resources.ResourcesManager.GetString("_enum_"+e.GetType().ToString().Replace('.','_'));
}
```

Error handling is a bit more..

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to have a function which maps between the enum value and the preferred short name and then create another function which generates the full message.

```
internal static string MapToName(ObjectTypes value) {
  switch (value) { 
    case ObjectTypes.TypeOne: return "T123";
    case ObjectTypes.TypeTwo: return "T234";
    ...
  }
}

public string ConvertToCustomTypeName(ObjectTypes value) {
  return String.Format("This is type {0}", MapToName(value));
}
```

Comment: It's obvious he wants to convert it to some arbitrary string, not the name of the enum field.

Comment: The prefix isnt' constant, the suffix isn't constant too, so I cant predict start of the string.

Comment: @dario, can you give us some more examples then?  It's hard to answer the question based on this limited sample

Comment: Sure, examples below:
"Cramshaft T124", "Low signal S", "High signal", "Overboost 1E", "Check engine!", "Fatal error", "Unknown", etc.

Answer (score 1):

I once used a custom attribute on the enum fields that took a string parameter and then wrote a function to extract the string when given an enum value.

Comment: Huh, didn't know enum members were attributable :).

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to use the name of enum (ie TypeOne ) you can simply call ToString() on the enum itself

```
typeObj.ToString()
```

If you want a custom string based on the type you have several different options.  The switch statement you have is OK but maintaining it will get messy if you have a large number of enums.  Or you could setup a dictionary based using the enum type as the key and the string as the value.

```
public enum ObectTypes
{
   One,
   Two
}

Dictionary<ObectTypes, String> myDic = new Dictionary<ObectTypes, string>();
myDic.Add( ObectTypes.One, "Something here for One" );
myDic.Add( ObectTypes.Two, "Something here for Two" );
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite believe this... why has nobody suggested a Resource file?

Mapping enum values to strings within compiled code is all well and good as a quick hack, but long term it is a bad practice and makes it difficult to refactor code. What if you add (or subtract) a value from the enum? If you use strings from a resource file all you have to do is add (or remove) one entry.

Comment: I don't think many C# programmers use the resource file.  It seems to be C++/win32/MFC coders who see the light of the resource file.

Comment: @Justin - i agree, not enough people are using them, possibly a bad habit left over from the old days of doing VB6 code etc. I think also as more people become aware of properly separating UI from the business logic (i.e. the MVVM pattern) then people will start using resource files more, especially as the resource files can be utilised as part of static binding.

Comment: -1 I disagree that it is bad practice at all, I've used this method for years with no pain. The only time it doesn't make sense is if the list has to by dynamic and frequently changes, at that point enums don't make sense regardless of using descriptions or not.

Comment: @Chris, you are entitled to disagree, and i notice that you have the top voted answer. And you are correct as long as your app is not multi lingual (even English has variants). Even when your app only targets a specific culture (say en-US) it is good practice to have the extra abstraction of placing the text into a resource file. In an n-tier app enums are usually declared in a low level common assembly, yet text is a UI thing and belongs in a UI related assembly. Your answer certainly *works*, but it isn't the *ideal* answer which is what i was trying to point out.

Comment: I would disagree that your solution is any more ideal than mine, I would say it's actually more problematic unless you need the additional abstraction for globalization. So to state a solution that is perfectly viable as bad practice is more than just a misnomer, it's a *WRONG* statement to make.

Answer (score 1):

I would put these values in a database. Roles usually belong in a database for several reasons including these:

1. Reports may need to be run against the roles, thus a need to display the descriptions.
2. Role definitions can be configured without deploying new code.
3. Roles should be enforced with a key constraint.

If done correctly, performance should not be an issue getting the roles from the database. Additionally, because a role definition table rarely changes, it is a very good candidate for caching.

If you find yourself having to hack around an Enum to get it to work, maybe you shouldn't use an Enum. Given the proper placement, everything should flow much better in code with little or no hacks. Granted Enums have their place; for example, a rather static mutually exclusive status.

Answer (score 0):

This calls for refactoring, I'd say.

[Replace Type Code With Class](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-type-code-with-class)

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with this, that would be over kill if it's really an enumeration that has code values and display values. I frequently use Enums to populate DropDowns.

Answer (score 0):

What you were already using isn't a bad pattern. Almost every other option has its own problems. If you were using F# for this type, you could do something like:

```
type ObjectTypes =
| TypeOne
| TypeTwo
| TypeThree
...
| TypeTwenty
with override this.ToString() =
    match this with
    | TypeOne -> "This is type T123"
    | TypeTwo -> "Oh man! This is type T234"
    ...
    | TypeTwenty -> "This is type last"
    | _ -> "This is any other type that wasn't explicitly specified"
```

Of course, with F# pattern matching, you have a lot more control than you would with a simple C# switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 8 greatly improves enum performance. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-8/#enums

> Other improvements were made to Enum as well. dotnet/runtime#76162
> improves the performance of various methods like ToString and
> IsDefined in cases where all of the enum‘s defined values are
> sequential starting from 0. In that common case, the internal function
> that looks up the value in the EnumInfo can do so
> with a simple array access, rather than needing to search for the
> target.